# How to create a comment with \pgfversion

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I would like to create a comment in my Latex (.tex) file as follows:

`% My pgf version is: 3.1.9a`

except that the version number ("3.1.9a" in the example above) comes from the `\pgfversion` command.

Is there a way to do this?

Note: In my opinion the PGF version is better tucked away in the .tex file as a comment rather than being printed out in the document I create. My issue is that all text following the '%' comment line initiator is treated literally as comment text. I use MiKTeX in Windows and TeX Live in Ubuntu. The answer should be compatible with both.

Comment: you are editing your tex source, so it isn't a tex question, you can do this with your editor scripting or sed or perl or Lua... (why would you want this though?)

Comment: a sample TeX file (one month's Lunar Distance star maps in a stereographic projection) is over 42.000 lines of LaTeX. I don't like the idea of post-processing this programmatically. I think outputting the PGF version in the document itself is not relevant to the subject contents. It could be very useful within a .tex file when hunting errors from other users.

Comment: then you want something like the script I posted run once when the file was created, saying it was tested with that version of pgf, having latex update it every time it runs wouldn't seem so useful. And why just the pgf version? the version of latex would seem as important or pgfplots (if you use that)

Comment: "I don't like the idea of post-processing this programmatically." isn't that exactly what you are asking for, or do I misunderstand the question? You want _something_ (latex, or lua or perl, or ...) to edit the generated tex file and modify a comment line?

Comment: You're (as always) right. I buy it! THANK YOU FOR ALL YOUR FEEDBACK :-)

Answer (score 3):

if you save the Lua script below as `pgfv.lua`

and have a file say `myfile.tex` that has a comment

```
% My pgf version is: anything
```

then running

```
texlua pgfv.lua myfile.tex
```

will update `myfile.tex` so that the comment has your current pgf version

```
% My pgf version is: 3.1.9a
```

**NOTE** this script re-writes the file with minimal error checks, back it up before running this.

---

Lua script;

```lua
-- get pgf version file
kpse.set_program_name("kpsewhich")
local pgfr=kpse.lookup("pgf.revision.tex")
local f = assert(io.open(pgfr, "r"))
local content = f:read("*all")
f:close()

-- extract version string
local v,v2,pgfversion = string.find(content,"pgfversion{([^}]*)")



local myfile = io.open(arg[1], "r")
local content = myfile:read("*all")
myfile:close()

print ("% My pgf version is: " .. pgfversion)

-- edit comment
 content = string.gsub(content,
     "%% My pgf version is: %S*",
     "%% My pgf version is: " .. pgfversion)

-- update file BEWARE WRITES FILE
 local myfile = io.open(arg[1], "w")
 myfile:write(content)
 myfile:close()
```

Comment: Thanks, David, for your immediate response. Nevertheless is there a chance to add a feature request for LaTeX to enable \pgfversion to be placed within a comment line? I think this would be a meaningful enhancement.

Comment: @Aendie no as I said in my initial comment, it is completely out of scope for latex. latex never writes its own source files, it's hard to imagine how you could see that working.

Comment: @Aendie also why  do you want such a comment? It seems meaningless, if you write a file today and add a 3.1.9a comment and pgf gets updated to 3.1.9b tomorrow, why do you want to edit your document?

Comment: I get your point ... the comment in the .tex file would not be in sync with the generated PDF. Sadly, I overlooked that. The pgf version really belongs in the PDF file.

Comment: @Aendie note you can put it in the pdf metadata without printing it see pdfinfo of documents made with hyperref for example